# Is there some way to see the questions with a certain number of close-votes

Tags: support

Currently only 8 users can vote to close and a question needs 5 votes to be closed.

Is there a way to quickly see which questions have a high number of close votes (let's say, 2 or 3) so that you can help out on questions (off course if you agree)?

Comment: we can collect them here off course ;)

Comment: I also think that min(1/3*#of user able to closevote, 5) would be enough votes for a question to close.

Comment: +1 I was just going to ask the same question!

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this [answer on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28391/search-for-vote-to-close). Basically, once you get 10K rep you get super ninja tools. However, this doesn't help a new beta site.

I presume that moderators will also get access to these tools (regardless of rep).

Comment: On this site only 2k is needed... still this is a lot. Moderator election will be done in 2-3 weeks after the public beta.

Comment: That's correct...I have those tools on stackoverflow and they give you many different list to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

At least till we get temporary moderators we should consider open a thread on meta to debate closing questions. Perhaps, each answer to the question will be about a qn that we think should be closed and we can use the comments to debate the pros and cons.

Comment: If we do that, we should deleted answers when a particular question is closed. Otherwise, the numbers of answers will explode.

Comment: I am not sure if deleting answers is good as it hinders transparency. In any case, this is a temporary fix and we can close the meta thread once we have moderators.

Comment: I opened a thread: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213/list-of-candidate-questions-to-be-closed

Comment: You can sort answers by date, so the old ones will locate at the end of the list and won't be disturbing. There are oldest | newest | votes tabs next to the N Answers header.